# What is the correct way of implementing Routing and Navigation in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

When I do an `ng new some-app` it generates an `app.routes.ts` in `src/app/` but no `app-routing.module.ts`. I am a bit confused about the difference between these two files and their purpose. *[The Developer guide on Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router#importing-your-new-components)* mentions `app.routes.ts` where as the tutorial *[Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt5#add-the-approutingmodule)* mentions `app-routing.module.ts`.
I am on Debian GNU/Linux 12 and my versions are:
`node`: 18.13.0
`npm`: 9.2.0
`angular`: 17.0.8

Any ideas or explanations for me? Thank you and Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Angular v17, the CLI generates `standalone` applications without any `NgModules`.

If you want to follow a routing tutorial for standalone please have a look at the new [Angular.dev](https://angular.dev/tutorials/learn-angular/enable-routing), which is the new official doc site.

Long story short, yes every route should go into your `app.routes.ts` !